# (js/jquery) Selectorpicker by Name & date from table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i want make selector by daterange picker and name of person.But here my name picker wasnt worked properly. because im newbie for javacript,and still learn until now. i have tried for since 2 weeks ago for this bugs,and tried to found inspiration website through the internet,and didnt found untill now.maybe anybody could share website example for name/id selector from table using js/jquery.thanks

here my code.

`https://codepen.io/osn-learn/pen/abQqvLd`

here some code for name selector but with much of html,and i want make with js/jquery and post it into id/class into html element.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Input To Dropdown Demos</title>
    <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/darkly/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- begin input-to-dropdown sources -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="input-to-dropdown.css">
    <script src="input-to-dropdown.js"></script>
    <!-- end input-to-dropdown sources -->
</head>
<body>
        <form>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <div class="checkbox-group-1">
            <span>select by name :</span>
              <table>
                <tr>            
                  <td><input id="val1" type="checkbox"> <label for="val1">Alexa</label></td>
                  <td><input id="val2" type="checkbox"> <label for="val2">Avram</label></td>
                  <td><input id="val3" type="checkbox"> <label for="val3">Basia</label></td>
                  <td><input id="val4" type="checkbox"> <label for="val4">Bryar</label></td>
                  <td><input id="val4" type="checkbox"> <label for="val4">Cruz</label></td>
                  <td><input id="val4" type="checkbox"> <label for="val4">Dexter</label></td>
                  <td><input id="val4" type="checkbox"> <label for="val4">Dustin</label></td>
                  <td><input id="val4" type="checkbox"> <label for="val4">Hamilton</label></td>
                  <td><input id="val4" type="checkbox"> <label for="val4">Ifeoma</label></td>
                  <td><input id="val4" type="checkbox"> <label for="val4">Indigo</label></td>
                  <td><input id="val4" type="checkbox"> <label for="val4">Ishmael</label></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <script>inputsToDropdown('.checkbox-group-1', 'Select please', 'checkbox', '.checkbox-group-1', '.checkbox-group-1 table');</script>
          </div>
        </form>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>                    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you converting checkboxes to dropdown? If you want dropdown directly use it. Any specific reason to do so?